# Uniform Identification 1890 to 1915

Tags: united-states, military-records, 1900s-decade

My Grandfather, seen here on the horse, had to escape the Russian Army around the turn of the last century, eventually coming to America.  I do not recognize the uniform in this picture, but it looks more American rather than Russian. Can anyone tell me anything about this uniform?[image]

Comment: If you get no responses here, you might try on the [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+uniform).  There are over 100 questions specifically on uniform identification there.